# How to resize bbcode linked image to fix within the current div height and width?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a comment posting function where public user can link and display images using

Something like [img]http://www.google.com/img.png[/img]

Issue is that user may link to an image that is of extremely large height and width which is more than the height and width of the div it is in causing some overflow layout issues

Is there anyway I can resize the image such that it still fit in the div without losing the aspect ratio?

Alternatively can I use CSS something like set overflow to display scroll bar if that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply `max-width` and `max-height` to the `img` via CSS.

```
#my_selector img
{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, so long as the parent element's dimensions are known.

Comment: But doing that if the image height and width is 320 x 260 then the image will get distorted right? Since it is change to 200 x 200

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the images and ensure their dimensions are not higher than their parent element...

```
var imgs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('img'),
    parent,
    parentWidth,
    parentHeight;

for (var i = 0, length = imgs.length; i < length; i++) {
    parent = imgs[i].parentNode
    parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
    parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;

    if (imgs[i].width > parentWidth) {
        imgs[i].style.width = parentWidth + 'px';
        imgs[i].style.height = 'auto';
    } else (imgs[i].height > parentHeight) {
        imgs[i].style.height = parentHeight + 'px';
        imgs[i].style.width = 'auto';
    }

}
```